# What is the logic in this WHERE clause which I think has fewer parentheses than ideal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out the logic of the following WHERE clause which is in a Stored Procedure written by someone who is currently unavailable to explain it to me in person, and which I need to adapt for a new case in a new Stored Procedure.  In other words, I need to understand the intent of this before I can adapt it correctly for the new case.

```
AND (ObjectType = 'ManufacturingPart'
                    AND PartType IN('FINISHED PRODUCT', 'RAW MATERIAL')
                    OR ObjectType IN('PackagingBOMComponent', 'PackagingBOM', 'StandardPart'))
```

In Plain English my feeling is that the condition will be satisfied if one of the following is TRUE

1. ObjectType = 'ManufacturingPart' AND PartType IN ('FINISHED PRODUCT', 'RAW MATERIAL')
2. ObjectType IN ('PackagingBOMComponent', 'PackagingBOM', 'StandardPart')

Or, parenthesised as I would prefer (I'm a great one for defensive parentheses)

```
AND 
    (((ObjectType = 'ManufacturingPart' AND PartType IN ('FINISHED PRODUCT', 'RAW MATERIAL'))
OR 
    (ObjectType IN ('PackagingBOMComponent', 'PackagingBOM', 'StandardPart')))
```

Am I correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The order of operations is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the SQL Server documentation.

```
Level   Operators
1       ~ (Bitwise NOT)
2       * (Multiplication), / (Division), % (Modulus)
3       + (Positive), - (Negative), + (Addition), + (Concatenation), - (Subtraction), & (Bitwise AND), ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR), | (Bitwise OR)
4       =, >, <, >=, <=, <>, !=, !>, !< (Comparison operators)
5       NOT
6       AND
7       ALL, ANY, BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, OR, SOME
8       = (Assignment)
```

Since AND has a higher precedence than OR, your rewrite with defensive parentheses will have the same result as the original.

Personally I prefer defensive parens too. It's too hard to remember the NOT/AND/OR precedence and too easy to make it explicit with more parens.

Comment: I've just joined this company and I feel that the standard of SQL is pretty dire.  Unfortunately I'm not in a position to effect any change, but I'll make sure that all the SQL that I write will be defensively parenthesised.  After all, isn't one of the absolute rules of Clear Code that it should be self-documenting?